# How to construct sequences by induction?

Tags: real-analysis, induction

if $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an arbitrary sequence of reals. How do I start to construct, by induction, two real sequences $(a_{n})$ and $(b_{n})$ such that these criteria hold:

- $(a_{n})$ is increasing
- $(b_{n})$ is decreasing
- for all n$\in \mathbb{N}, a_{n} < b_{n}$
- the sequence $(b_{n} - a_{n})$ converges to 0.
- $u_{n} \notin [a_{n}, b_{n}]$

Comment: That last requirement $u_n \notin [a_n, b_n]$ seems to make the problem interesting.  Yet, you should attempt it yourself and/or put your thoughts.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know how to start.

Comment: What would you do if you temporarily ignored the last requirement?

Comment: I'm on it. Just taking a little longer than anticipated.

Comment: My guess is that your class is studying the "nested interval theorem" and/or related convergence theorems about nondecreasing sequences.

Comment: thinking about choosing 3 different initial values $a_{1}, b_{1}$ and C where $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ each converge towards C. But with an infinite sequence (the natural numbers), I can't figure out how to make the first step. [Would otherwise be: let Z be the number of elements in $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$. Initialize $a_{1}$ and $b_{1}$ and C = $\frac{a_{1} + b_{1}}{2}$, then $a_{2}  = a_{1} +\frac{2-1}{Z}*C$ and the same but with minus for $b_{n}$

Comment: Tricky. BTW does increasing / decreasing mean strictly increasing / decreasing?

Comment: yes, this is from exercises in a first course in real analysis for what that's worth

Comment: But, does the nested interval theorem require you to know the point of convergence in advance? [PS: I do not know what "Let $Z$ be the number of elements in $a_n$ and $b_n$" means]

Comment: I'm on it. Just some jerk on the 3rd floor stole some of my processing power, so it's taking longer than I hoped.

Comment: if $a_{n} = [0,1,2,...,99]$ then Z would be 100. The number of elements in $a_{n}$ = the number of elements in $b_{n}$ = Z.

Comment: You don't need to know  a priori the point of convergence of $(a_{n})_{n}$ and $(b_{n})_{n}$. For your first step: $u_{1}$ is a fixed point in $\boldsymbol{R}$, you have to choose $a_1$ and $b_{1}$ s.t. $a_1<b_1$ and $u_{1} \notin [a_{1}, b_{1}]$. Do you have any idea for the choice of $a_1$ and $b_1$?

Comment: $a_1=-100$ and $b_1=100$ seems to be a good choice, just about as good as any other number.

Comment: Well, you have to make sure that $u_{1} \notin [-100, 100]$

Comment: Yeah, of course. So let's make $a_1=-0.999|u_1|$ and $b_1=0.999|u_1|$. Oh wait, it can be 0. Forget it. Let $a_1=u_1+1$ and $b_1=u_1+2$.

Comment: but aren't the reals basically the real numbers?

Comment: Indeed they are. So what?

Comment: then it becomes tougher to choose an interval such that $u_{n} \notin [a_{n},b_{n}]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope. You make every interval the same as previous, unless $u_n$ happens to be in it; otherwise you shift the closest border inwards so as to leave that $u_n$ outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary initial interval $a_0<b_0$. If this interval contains $u_0$, trim it on one side by keeping one of $\left[\dfrac{u_0+b_0}2,b_0\right]$ or $\left[a_0,\dfrac{a_0+u_0}2\right]$.

Shrink this interval, for instance with $a_1=\dfrac{2a_0+b_0}3,b_1=\dfrac{a_0+2b_0}3$. If the new interval contains $u_1$, trim it on one side by keeping one of $\left[\dfrac{u_1+b_1}2,b_1\right]$ or $\left[a_1,\dfrac{a_1+u_1}2\right]$.

And so on.

You can easily check that those intervals are non-empty, nested, do not contain the respective $u_n$ and their size converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(u_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a fixed sequence, wlog you can assume $u_1$ to be positive (if it is negative you can make the same argument as below, if it is 0 you can take $a_1=1$ and $b_1=2$). First step: choose $a_{1}=\frac{u_1}{4}$ and $b_1=\frac{u_1}{2}$. Now $a_{1}<b_{1}$ and $u_{1} \notin [a_{1}, b_{1}]$. Supppose you have constructed $a_n$ and $b_n$ satisfiyng the assumptions. Now $u_{n+1}$ can be in $[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]$ or in $[\frac{a_n+b_n}{2},b_n]$ (if it is outside $[a_n,b_n]$ you can just take $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{b_{n}-a_{n}}{2^{10}}$ and $b_{n+1}=b_n-\frac{b_{n}-a_{n}}{2^{10}}$). Assume $u_{n+1}\in[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}]$ (the other case is similar), you take $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}+\frac{b_{n}-a_{n}}{2^{10}}$ and $b_{n+1}=b_n-\frac{b_{n}-a_{n}}{2^{10}}$.You have to check that this choice of $a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}$ satisfies your assumptions and use the nested interval theorem for the convergence of the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the set $(u_n)$ is countable there is a real $x$ such that $x\neq u_n$$ \forall n$. Therefore for every $n$ we can choose the interval $[a_n,b_n]$ so that $x\in[a_n,b_n]$, $u_n\notin[a_n,b_n]$ and to addition $[a_n,b_n]\subset[a_{n-1},b_{n-1}],n\ge2$. Then $(a_n),(b_n)$ are required sequences.